# How To Allow Some Urls, and Block Others based on a few conditions

Tags: javascript

Basically I have a variable to work with that provides the url of a certain image $member_profile_image. I'm trying to check for that url, and then find the word "Default" in it. I've done that, the indexOf comes up as 22. That lets me know that someone has not uploaded a photo to their profile. If they haven't uploaded a profile photo I'd like them to only be able to access the links I have stored in the array myurls. So if the upload indexOf is indeed 22, and they are on one of those pages stored in myurls, I want nothing at all to happen, but if they try to go to any other page, I want the to be redirected to the page to upload a photo. I'm pretty new to all of this, so I'm probably way off here. The only thing I've managed to do so far is be redirected to the page where the photo gets uploaded, but it keeps reloading the page over and over again. Code Below:

```
<script>
var image = "$member_profile_image"
var upload = image.indexOf("Default");
var myurls = new Array(3);
myurls[0] = "http://websiteforyou.spruz.com/?page=login&cmd=c&id=7394750B-F821-48B6-B6AC-1508D1932390&c=eb3hb4el98";
myurls[1] = "http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/?page=login&cmd=confirm";
myurls[2] = "http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com";
myurls[3] = "http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal";
if(myurls[0,1,2] = window.location && upload == "22")
alert("have a great day");
else
alert("You have to upload a profile image to participate on this site");
window.location.replace("http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal");
</script>
```

Comment: I must have really butchered this one up good. No one? lol

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're doing, so I made a lot of assumptions!
In general your biggest mistake is `myurls[0,1,2,3] = window.location` both because `myurls[0,1,2,3]` is invalid javascript and `=` doesn't compare but assigns.

I've made an example of what I believe the code should have been and I just hope I'm right.

```
var image   = <?php echo json_encode($member_profile_image) ?>,
    upload  = image.indexOf('Default') === 22,
    myurls  = [
        'http://websiteforyou.spruz.com/?page=login&cmd=c&id=7394750B-F821-48B6-B6AC-1508D1932390&c=eb3hb4el98',
        'http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/?page=login&cmd=confirm',
        'http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com',
        'http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal'
    ];

if (myurls.indexOf(window.location) > -1 && upload) {
    alert('have a great day');
}
else {
    alert('You have to upload a profile image to participate on this site');
    window.location.replace('http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal');
}
```

If using IE8- you'll have to implement `indexOf` for the `Array` yourself (or use a polyfill)

Also assuming it's your domain and it doesn't change, you could just check the url path, like so:

```
var image   = <?php echo json_encode($member_profile_image) ?>,
    upload  = image.indexOf('Default') === 22,
    myurls  = [
        '/?page=login&cmd=c&id=7394750B-F821-48B6-B6AC-1508D1932390&c=eb3hb4el98',
        '/?page=settings&cmd=personal',
        '/?page=login&cmd=confirm',
        ''
    ];

if (myurls.indexOf(window.location.pathname) > -1 && upload) {
    alert('have a great day');
}
else {
    alert('You have to upload a profile image to participate on this site');
    window.location.replace('/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal');
}
```

Comment: :face-palm: - Of course! I entirely overlooked the method of checking if the url was in the array - focusing entirely on 'but it keeps reloading the page over and over again' Good catch! No need to see me to the door, I'll let myself out..

Comment: I gave this a go, and it didn't run at all. I didn't give enough info, and I apologize. I think part of my description lacked that $member_profile_image displays the url on the page as text, and the <php echo json, I don't believe is needed in that aspect. As well, I don't have server access, and Php is not usable and blocked on the platform. That's why I had everything in " " because I'm literally having to work with text, and not an actual php variable. That's why "$member_profile_image" and "22" were the approaches that I was taking. Was I wrong in that?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What exactly doesn't work? What is the result you get? Do you receive any errors?

Answer (score -1):

after the else statement, you need to wrap the alert and the location replace with { } - As it stands, the window.location line will be run regardless of the result of the if check.

That is to say, change

```
if(myurls[0,1,2,3] = window.location && upload == "22")
alert("have a great day");
else
alert("You have to upload a profile image to participate on this site");
window.location.replace("http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal");
```

to this:

```
if(myurls[0,1,2,3] = window.location && upload == "22")
  alert("have a great day");
else
{
  alert("You have to upload a profile image to participate on this site");
  window.location.replace("http://www.websiteforyou.spruz.com/member/?page=settings&cmd=personal");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I put those brackets in like suggested, but I'm still getting the same result. The alert "have a great day" is just a test to see if that aspect of the script is being ran properly. If I go to any of the urls listed within the myurls array however, I never receive that alert. It always instead alerts the else statement. It seems like somethings likely wrong with my if statement or the array itself isn't right. Any ideas?